# How to add multiple values with add_query_arg?

Tags: query

Let's suppose I am on this url of my site http://demo.com/?cat=1+2+3

And now someone clicks on a link generated with add_query_arg(). How can I make this link go to http://demo.com/?cat=1+2+3+4

Im trying to create a taxonomy filter and this is what I have:

```
foreach ( $sub_terms as $st ) {
    echo '<a href="'. esc_url( add_query_arg( $taxonomy, $st->term_id ,"http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" ) ).'" class="subterm">'. $st->name .'</a>';
}
```

Instead of appending my term id to the url, it just replaces cat with the new value: http://demo.com/?cat=4

I hope it's clear enough

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to create the link or process the request?

Comment: Trying to create the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not "smart" enough to reason that you want to modify the value, not just set it to something.

You'll need to:

1. retrieve the current value (`get_query_var()` probably)
2. change it as needed
3. use resulting value with `add_query_arg()`